# toggle one element and hide the rest under same wrapper class

Tags: javascript, jquery

**jQuery:**

```
$("#star_btn1").click(function() {
$('#ca').toggle();
// I would like to hide everything EXCEPT CA under parent wrapper .allthestates 

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="allthestates">

<!-- there are div ids here with every 50 states, all states are display none in css by default, the problem is the JS -->

<div id="ca">content</div>

</div>
```

So click button `#star_btn1` then id `#ca` under `.allthestates` displays -- everything else will not.

Comment: There is no `#ca` in `.allthestates`. Show all HTML please - Anyway, if you target one specific element with its ID as you do, others element won't be affected.

Comment: `$('#ca').show().siblings().hide()` ? Is that it?

Comment: What about adding a class to the states such as `.states` then you can hide/show these as a group and hide/show `#ca` independently even if they are under the same parent.

Comment: If you want to make 50 buttons using `id` is bad idea. Look an example
http://jsfiddle.net/1crLLus7/

Comment: Please improve this question by including the HTML code you are working on

Comment: @FullDecent what does the HTML have to do with anything?! Cant you imagine 50 divs with with id of states?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the ":not()" selector and the ">" (immediate children), you can do something like this:

```
$("#star_btn1").click(function() {
    $('.allthestates > :not(#ca)').hide();
    $('#ca').show();
});

<div class="allthestates">
   <div class="state" id="CA">California</div>
   <div class="state" id="TX">Texas</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, everything else doesn't have a specific class. I can't do that because I will be making 50 buttons for every state. I would have to make a ton more classes to identify everything else for each button.

Comment: the .not or :not() operator avoids these situations.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I was guessing on a very vague example of HTML.

Comment: I changed it to use the :not() selector on everything other than `#ca` element.

Comment: Hi Mr. @KJPrice I downvoted it because it was the worst solution for scalability! But your revised is excellent!

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has the "not" function you can call to exclude any elements you wish.

```
$("#star_btn1").click(function() {
$('.allthestates').children().not('#ca').toggle();
// I would like to hide everything EXCEPT CA under parent wrapper .allthestates 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp

```
$(".allthestates:not(.allthestates #ca)").hide();
```

With the help of Vohuman, we came to this even better result:

```
$(".allthestates > :not(#ca)").hide();
```

The ">" selector gets all the direct childs from the first selector, and from that collection we exclude the one with id "#ca".

Comment: The `:not` here excludes a `.allthestates` element that doesn't have `ca` id from the set.

Comment: @Vohuman you're right, corrected my code.

Comment: Sorry, the current selector doesn't make a lot of sense, it excludes a child from a set of parents. How about: `$(".allthestates > :not(#ca)").hide()`?

Comment: @Vohuman I might be editing too fast. :) it did make sense, in a strange, abstract way. ;-) But as your solution makes sense in a not-so-abstract way, I re-edited. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#star_btn1").click(function() {
    $('.allthestates').children().hide().filter('#ca').show();
});
```